# i want an animation view when the game ends. and my animationView will appear first then next is congratulationview animated.?

Tags: swift, animation, uiviewcontroller, popupwindow

this is my code thank you can someone know how to do that?

this scene is when the the game is over

```swift
func prepareTimeCount() {
  self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1,
                                    target: self,
                                    selector: #selector(self.timeCount),
                                    userInfo: nil,
                                    repeats: true)
}

func prepareWinView() {
  let images:NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
  for i in 1...12
  {
      let image = UIImage(named:"animationView\(i).png")
      images.add(image!)

  }
  self.congratulationView.animationImages = images as [AnyObject] as? [UIImage]
  self.congratulationView.animationDuration = 3
  self.congratulationView.startAnimating()
  self.view.addSubview(self.congratulationView)
}

@objc func timeCount() {
  var timeCount = Int(self.timeCountLabel!.text!) ?? 0
  if(timeCount <= 0 ) {
      self.timer.invalidate()
      self.gameOver()
  } else {
      timeCount-=1
  }
  self.timeCountLabel.text = String(timeCount)
}

func gameOver() {
  self.isGameOver = true
  self.birdView.stopAnimating()
  self.timer.invalidate()
}
```

and here is the codes when the game ends

```swift
func gameWin() {
  let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
  defaults.setValue("\(self.levelNomber)", forKey: "level")

  self.txtMessageTitle.text = "Congratulations"
  self.txtMessageSubTitle.text = "You won the game"

  self.isGameOver = true
  self.birdView.stopAnimating()
  viewMessage.isHidden = false
  congratulationView.isHidden = false
  self.timer.invalidate()
}
```

can someone help me solve this error?

i want the the animation will see first before the congratulation messages appear. thank you